How to filter a table based on a particular date in power BI
I have the below table in power BI and I want to perform 2 things:

I want to filter the table based on date. I.e, I want to filter only 01-Jan values.
Once I get the 1st Jan values I want to calculate the difference between 2 dates.

Below is what I have:



Date
Value




1-Jan-2020
5.5


2-Jan-2020
6.2


1-Jan-2021
14.2


2-Jan-2021
3.4



.
.
I want to achieve below:



Date
Value
difference




1-Jan-2020
5.5
Difference between value col [14.2-5.5]


1-Jan-2021
14.2





Below is the table of values I have got after adding a column.



**NAV
Date
Column      **




360.9914
Monday, January 1, 2024
y


312.3794
Monday, January 2, 2023
y


277.4562
Monday, January 3, 2022
y


190.9738
Friday, January 1, 2021
y


139.8156
Wednesday, January 1, 2020
y



Now I want to calculate the difference between the NAV column rows, with the current measure it is working like below:



**Nav_Diff_Measure
Column
Year**





y
2024


49.33
y
2023


35.49
y
2022



y
2021


51.16
y
2020



Expected Output is :



**Nav_Diff_Measure
Column
Year**





y
2024


49.33
y
2023


35.49
y
2022


87.24
y
2021


51.16
y
2020



Issue is that it is not calculating difference for 2021 year.I would like to show negative values as well if applicable, as I'm planning put a data bar for this value.Below is the image link where the table image is clear.Kindly help to get the negative values as well.
[Current working image][1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/fzC5W4h6.png

pls try this
measure =
VAR _next =
    MINX (
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Table' ),
            'Table'[Date] > MAX ( 'Table'[Date] )
                && 'Table'[Column] = "y"
        ),
        'Table'[Date]
    )
VAR next_value =
    SUMX ( FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[Date] = _next ), 'Table'[NAV] )
VAR _last =
    MAXX ( FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[Column] = "y" ), 'Table'[Date] )
RETURN
    IF (
        MAX ( 'Table'[Date] ) = _last,
        BLANK (),
        next_value - SUM ( 'Table'[NAV] )
    )



This works fine for all years. Thank you so much for your support.

I think you need a filter column.
column = if(month('Table'[Date])=1 && day('Table'[Date])=1,"y")


then create a measure
Measure =
VAR _next =
    SUMX (
        FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[Date] = EDATE ( MAX ( 'Table'[Date] ), 12 ) ),
        'Table'[Value]
    )
RETURN
    IF ( NOT ( ISBLANK ( _next ) ), _next - SUM ( 'Table'[Value] ) )



Hi, Thanks for responding and this solution works fine. But while testing I found that if Jan 1st is saturday or sunday it will be left blank without adding "y"[My bad had forgotten to mention this in earlier question that only weekdays to be considered].I tried to tweak the code as below but not getting desired output:
Column_Jan1 = if(month('Nav-Data'[Date])=1 && (day('Nav-Data'[Date])=1 && WEEKDAY('Nav-Data'[Date]) IN {2,3,4,5,6}) ,"y")

Hi, want to take 1 more help. while calculating the diff between 2 rows if the value is negative it is not calculating the value and is leaving the table cell blank as below. It is showing up difference for year 23,22,20 but 21 is empty. 2024 is blank as we dont have 2025 jan 1st value yet. Showing the values in next comment as there is a limit on characters entered.

NAV   Date                      Column diff
360.9914 Mon , Jan 1, 2024   y   NA.
312.3794 Mon, Jan 2, 2023 y 49.33 277.4562 Mon, Jan 3, 2022 y 35.49 190.9738 Fri, Jan 1, 2021 y this should be -86.48 (277.45-190.97) 139.8156 Wed, Jan 1, 2020 y 51.16

could you pls paste the expected output in your original post? It's very hard to read it in the comment.

Have added the image link and expected output in original question.

you can try this to get the first weekday of each year
Column =
IF (
    'Table'[Date]
        = MINX (
            FILTER (
                'Table',
                YEAR ( 'Table'[Date] ) = YEAR ( EARLIER ( 'Table'[Date] ) )
                    && WEEKDAY ( 'Table'[Date], 1 ) IN { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }
            ),
            'Table'[Date]
        ),
    "y"
)



Hi, I tried the above code but pbi is not recognising the column name. It underlines the column name in red and when I hover it shows 'Cannot find name [Date]' as an error.

Hi, I tried the above but pbi is not recognising the column name. It underlines the column name in red and it shows 'Cant find name [Date]'. It is showing for 3rd line in the below code.                                                                          Nav-Diff_M =
IF (
'Nav-Data'[Date]
= MINX (
FILTER (
'Nav-Data'
YEAR ( 'Nav-Data'[Date] ) = YEAR ( EARLIER ( 'Nav-Data'[Date] ) )
&& WEEKDAY ( 'Nav-Data'[Date] , 1 ) IN { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }
),
'Nav-Data'[Date]
),
"y"
)

Am I missing anything?

Date is the column name. What's your date column name? You need to change to that name.

Date is my column name as well. Have changed it to 'Date' only. NAV and Date are the 2 columns that I have.

sry, I forgot to change the measure to column. Are you creating a measure or column? I think you need to use DAX to create a new column. I will update my DAX.

Heyyyy Super, this works fine. Thank you so much. Creating column in DAX works fine. Thanks again.

you are welcome. pls accept my answer as a solution. thanks.

Have accepted the answer. Let me know if anything else that I should do. Thanks.
